# Drawing rounders corners on 315° arc

Tags: swift, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I am drawing an arc that is 270° and has rounded coners on both ends. This is working fine, however now I would like to change my arch to be 315° (-45°), but then my corner calculation won't work.

I have tried to calculate this different ways but can't seem to find the formula for making a general function to add rounded corners to my arc when the start and ends are not vertical och horizontal.

This is my playground code:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ArcView: UIView {

  private var strokeWidth: CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(min(self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height) * 0.25)
  }
  private let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 10

  override open func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    drawNormalCircle()
  }

  func drawNormalCircle() {
    let strokeWidth = CGFloat(min(self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height) * 0.25)
    let innerRadius = (min(self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height) - strokeWidth*2) / 2.0
    let outerRadius = (min(self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height)) / 2.0

    var endAngle: CGFloat = 270.0
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: self.center, radius: outerRadius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: endAngle * .pi / 180, clockwise: true)

    var point = bezierPath.currentPoint
    point.y += cornerRadius
    let arc = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: point, radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: 180 * .pi / 180, endAngle: 270 * .pi / 180, clockwise: true)
    arc.apply(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (360 - endAngle) * .pi / 180))

    var firstCenter = bezierPath.currentPoint
    firstCenter.y += cornerRadius

    bezierPath.addArc(withCenter: firstCenter, radius: cornerRadius , startAngle: 270 * .pi / 180 , endAngle: 0, clockwise: true)
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bezierPath.currentPoint.x, y: strokeWidth - cornerRadius))

    var secondCenter = bezierPath.currentPoint
    secondCenter.x -= cornerRadius
    bezierPath.addArc(withCenter: secondCenter, radius: cornerRadius , startAngle: 0, endAngle: 90 * .pi / 180, clockwise: true)
    bezierPath.addArc(withCenter: self.center, radius: innerRadius, startAngle: 270 * .pi / 180, endAngle: 0, clockwise: false)

    var thirdCenter = bezierPath.currentPoint
    thirdCenter.x += cornerRadius
    bezierPath.addArc(withCenter: thirdCenter, radius: cornerRadius , startAngle: 180 * .pi / 180, endAngle: 270 * .pi / 180, clockwise: true)

    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bezierPath.currentPoint.x + strokeWidth - (cornerRadius * 2), y: bezierPath.currentPoint.y))

    var fourthCenter = bezierPath.currentPoint
    fourthCenter.y += cornerRadius
    bezierPath.addArc(withCenter: fourthCenter, radius: cornerRadius , startAngle: 270 * .pi / 180, endAngle: 0, clockwise: true)

    bezierPath.close()

    let backgroundLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    backgroundLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
    backgroundLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    backgroundLayer.lineWidth = 2
    backgroundLayer.fillColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor

    self.layer.addSublayer(backgroundLayer)
  }
}

let arcView = ArcView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = arcView
```

The problem for me is how to calculate the arc center for the corners when the corner is not a given X - CornerRadius, or Y + corner Radius, which it is in perfectly horizontal or vertical cases. How can I have rounded corners when the arc is 315°.

Comment: My advice for any path drawing: draw it on paper. Label the components, and extract them out into tiny simple parts.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I actually have done that, tried to calculate it using `cos` but somehow I don't seem to get it right. It is using paper I came up with the above.

Comment: Honestly I don't think this is something someone can fix without spending a lot of time trying to understand your existing code, which no offence, is really complex. There's a lot of things that are poorly labelled, lots of unexplained arithmetic. It's the kind of thing that would make perfect sense for the author, but would be really hard for anyone else to pick up. I would recommend you decompose the solution into smaller structs. I see at least two here, dying to get out: `RoundedDiskSector`, which as four `RoundedCornerDescriptor`s

Comment: Thank you for your opinion and suggestion. I am trying to figure it whilst I have this question posten, if I get it before someone else is able to explain it, I'll surely answer the question myself.

Comment: This was fun! I almost have it figured out https://imgur.com/a/osXkVO9 I just need to calculate the inset angles for the inner/outter arcs' start/end points

Comment: Man I've learned so much trying to get this work. Lo and behold, it works. I have some bugs related to the angle bridging I implemented when porting to AppKit, but the geometry of the shape is perfect! https://gfycat.com/pleasanthandyagama

Comment: Nice work. Care to share your solution? Eager to know how _you_ solved it.

Comment: Absolutely. It'll take me a little while. I've been writing the answer (not the code, the code's done, just the explanatory answer) for over an hour now lol. I'm going to bed, but I'll finish it tomorrow morning (Eastern time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's my solution. 
It's just simple trigonometry

```
/// Create a path made with 6 small subpaths
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - startAngle: the start angle of the path in cartesian plane angles system
///   - endAngle: the end angle of the path in cartesian plane angles system
///   - outerRadius: the radius of the outer circle in % relative to the size of the view that holds it
///   - innerRadius: the radius of the inner circle in % relative to the size of the view that holds it
///   - cornerRadius: the corner radius of the edges
///
/// - Returns: the path itself
func createPath(from startAngle: Double, to endAngle: Double,
                outerRadius:CGFloat, innerRadius:CGFloat,
                cornerRadius: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    let maxDim = min(view.frame.width, view.frame.height)
    let oRadius: CGFloat = maxDim/2 * outerRadius
    let iRadius: CGFloat = maxDim/2 * innerRadius
    let center = CGPoint.init(x: view.frame.width/2, y: view.frame.height/2)

    let startAngle = deg2rad(360.0 - startAngle)
    let endAngle = deg2rad(360.0 - endAngle)

    // Outer Finish Center point
    let ofcX = center.x + (oRadius - cornerRadius) * CGFloat(cos(endAngle - deg2rad(360)))
    let ofcY = center.y + (oRadius - cornerRadius) * CGFloat(sin(endAngle - deg2rad(360)))

    // Inner Finish Center point
    let ifcX = center.x + (iRadius + cornerRadius) * CGFloat(cos(endAngle - deg2rad(360)))
    let ifcY = center.y + (iRadius + cornerRadius) * CGFloat(sin(endAngle - deg2rad(360)))

    // Inner Starting Center point
    let iscX = center.x + (iRadius + cornerRadius) * CGFloat(cos(startAngle - deg2rad(360)))
    let iscY = center.y + (iRadius + cornerRadius) * CGFloat(sin(startAngle - deg2rad(360)))

    // Outer Starting Center point
    let oscX = center.x + (oRadius - cornerRadius) * CGFloat(cos(startAngle - deg2rad(360)))
    let oscY = center.y + (oRadius - cornerRadius) * CGFloat(sin(startAngle - deg2rad(360)))


    // Outer arch
    path.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: oRadius,
                startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle,
                clockwise: true)

    // Rounded outer finish
    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: ofcX, y: ofcY), radius: cornerRadius,
                startAngle: endAngle, endAngle:endAngle +  deg2rad(90),
                clockwise: true)

    // Rounded inner finish
    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: ifcX, y: ifcY), radius: cornerRadius,
                startAngle: endAngle +  deg2rad(90), endAngle: endAngle +  deg2rad(180),
                clockwise: true)

    // Inner arch
    path.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: iRadius,
                startAngle: endAngle, endAngle: startAngle,
                clockwise: false)

    // Rounded inner start
    path.addArc(withCenter:  CGPoint(x: iscX, y: iscY), radius: cornerRadius,
                startAngle:  startAngle + deg2rad(180), endAngle:  startAngle + deg2rad(270),
                clockwise: true)

    // Rounded outer start
    path.addArc(withCenter:  CGPoint(x: oscX, y: oscY), radius: cornerRadius,
                startAngle:  startAngle + deg2rad(270), endAngle:  startAngle,
                clockwise: true)

    return path
}

func deg2rad(_ number: Double) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(number * .pi / 180)
}
```

Usage:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var mainView: UIView!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    borderLayer.path = createPath(from: 30, to: 120, outerRadius: 0.9, innerRadius: 0.3, cornerRadius: 5).cgPath
    borderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
    borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
    borderLayer.lineWidth = 0.0
    mainView.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It was the `cos` and `sin` part I had most difficulty with, and reading your answer I know why. You calculate it from center.x. I was stuck trying to calculate it from the endAngle of the latest drawn arc. Again, thank you.

Comment: Added a `atan` calculation to the calculations of the start- and endAngle's for both the inner and outer radius in order to have the rounding negative to the start and ending of the arc. I have chosen your answer and the correct answer, however @alexanders answer is just as correct, but harder to follow for future dev looking to find and answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

Preface: usually when my answer to a question is "do something completely different,"  I aim to fix the original problem as is, and then also suggest the better approach in addition. However, that's unfeasible for this one, because the complexity of this code, if it were to be expanded in the same style, grows so immensely that it just wasn't worth it.

The problem here is fundamentally that of code organization. Many expressions are repeated by copy-pasting. Extracting them to a variable would not only give a central place for editing, but it also gives a name to the expression, immensely improving readability.

This code will be long. But that's okay, because it's going to be simple. Having a bunch of simple stuff almost always beats a small amount of complex stuff. You might be able to write some crazy trig code that lays out your bezier curve perfectly, but chances are, you won't get it right the first time. Debugging will be hard. It will be totally foreign, and way harder to anyone who isn't you ...and that includes future you. Future you will struggle.

Before we start, here's a rough diagram to help you orient yourself with the rest of this post:

[image: Overview diagram]

## A visual development environment

Firstly, we need to establish a good way to visualize our results.

Playground can quickly reload previews, so that's a plus. But debugging with closed paths is hard, because it's hard to tell the individual sections of a bezier path apart, and often times for convex shapes, the path will close over itself in a way that obscures the part of the path you're working on. So the first part of the code I would work on, is an abstraction layer for `UIBezierPath`

To remedy this, I'm going to develop the shape by stroking each section in a different colour. Unfortunately, you can't stroke a subsection of a `UIBezierPath` separately from the rest, so to achieve this, our shape will need to be composed of multiple `UIBezierPath`s, stroking each one as we go along. But this could be slow in performance-sensitive contexts, so ideally we only want to be doing this during development. I want to be able to pick between one of two different ways to do the same thing. Protocols are perfect for that, so let's start there.

I'll start with `BezierPathBuilder`. All it does is allow me append `BezierPathRenderable` parts to it (which I'll get to later), and build a final path, which I can hand off to my `CALayer` or whatever.

```
protocol BezierPathBuilder: AnyObject {
    func append(_: BezierPathRenderable)
    func build() -> UIBezierPath
}
```

The main implementation of this protocol is really simple, it just wraps a `UIBezierPath`. When the `renderable` is told to render itself, it'll simply operate on the path we give it, without needing to allocate any intermediate paths.

```
class BezierPathBuilderImpl: BezierPathBuilder {
    let path = UIBezierPath()

    func append(_ renderable: BezierPathRenderable) {
        renderable.render(into: self, self.path)
    }
    func build() -> UIBezierPath {
        return path
    }
}
```

The debug implementation is a bit more interesting. When appending a `renderable`, we don't let it draw itself directly into our main path. Instead, we make a new temporary path for it to use, where it'll draw itself. We then have the opportunity to stroke that path (with a different colour every time). Once we've done that, we can append that temporary path to the main path, and resume.

```
class DebugBezierPathBuilder: BezierPathBuilder {

    var rainbowIterator = ([
        .red, .orange, .yellow, .green, .cyan, .blue, .magenta, .purple ] as Array<UIColor>).makeIterator()

    let path = UIBezierPath()

    func append(_ renderable: BezierPathRenderable) {
        let newPathSegment = UIBezierPath()
        renderable.render(into: self, newPathSegment)

        // This will crash if you use too many colours, but it suffices for now.
        rainbowIterator.next()!.setStroke()
        newPathSegment.lineWidth = 20
        newPathSegment.stroke()

        path.append(newPathSegment)
    }

    func build() -> UIBezierPath {
        return path
    }
}
```

## Objectifying our geometry

In your code, there's no separation between geometry calculations and drawing. As a result, you can't easily define one component in reference to another, because you don't have a way of "fishing out" that last arc you drew in the UIBezierPath, or whatever. So let's remedy that.

First of all, I'll define a protocol, `BezierPathRenderable`, which our program will use to define what it means for an entity to be renderable to a `BezierPath`.

```
protocol BezierPathRenderable {
    func render(into builder: BezierPathBuilder, _ path: UIBezierPath)
}
```

This design isn't my favourite, but it's the best I could come up with. The two parameters here allow the conforming type to either draw itself directly into the `path`, or call `append` on the `builder`. The latter is useful for aggregate shapes that are composed out of simpler constituents (sound familiar?)

### Wish oriented development

My favourite process for writing code involves scaffolding out a whole bunch of stuff early on, writing whatever parts of the code are interesting to me, and just adding stub implementations left-and-right. Every step of the way, I'm essentially answering the question "what API do I wish I had right now?", and then I stub it, and pretend that it exists.

#### Stubbing the main shape

I'll start with the main structure. We want an object that models a [sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector) of an [annulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics)) with rounded corners. This object would have to do two things:

1. Store all values that parameterized shape
2. Define a way to render the shape, by conforming to `BezierPathRenderable`

So let's start with that:

```
struct RoundedAnnulusSector: BezierPathRenderable {
    let center: CGPoint
    var innerRadius: CGFloat
    var outerRadius: CGFloat
    var startAngle: Angle
    var endAngle: Angle
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat

    func render(into builder: BezierPathBuilder, _ path: BezierPath) {
        /// ???
    }
```

#### Preparing some rendering code

Let's write some scaffolding code to draw this using our new rendering system. For now I'll be using our debugging strokes to render, so I'll comment out the `CAShapeLayer` stuff:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ArcView: UIView {
    private var strokeWidth: CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(min(self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height) * 0.25)
    }

    override open func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        let innerRadius = (min(self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height) - strokeWidth*2) / 2.0
        let outerRadius = (min(self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height)) / 2.0

        let shape = RoundedAnnulusSector(
            center: self.center,
            innerRadius: innerRadius - 50,
            outerRadius: outerRadius - 50,
            startAngle: (45 * .pi) / 180,
            endAngle: (315 * .pi) / 180,
            cornerRadius: 25
        )
        let builder = DebugBezierPathBuilder()
        builder.append(shape)
        let path = builder.build()

        let backgroundLayer = CAShapeLayer()
//      backgroundLayer.path = path.cgPath
//      backgroundLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
//      backgroundLayer.lineWidth = 2
//      backgroundLayer.fillColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor

        self.layer.addSublayer(backgroundLayer)
    }
}

let arcView = ArcView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 800))
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = arcView
```

This obviously does nothing, because we haven't implemented `RoundedAnnulusSector.render(into:_:)`.

#### Stubbing the corners

We can notice that the entirety of this shape's drawing hinges upon the details of its 4 corners. If our shape has four corners, why don't we just say that?

```
struct RoundedAnnulusSector: BezierPathRenderable {
    // ...

    private var corner1: RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner { ??? }
    private var corner2: RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner { ??? }
    private var corner3: RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner { ??? }
    private var corner4: RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner { ??? }
}
```

In writing that, I wished that a structure existed called `RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner`, which would do two things:

1. Store all values that parameterized shape
2. Define a way to render the shape, by conforming to `BezierPathRenderable`

Notice they're the same two roles that `RoundedAnnulusSector` fulfills. These things are intentionally simple, and meant to be composable.

For now we can just stub `RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner`

```
struct RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner {}
```

...and fill in our computed properties to return default instances. Next we'll want to define the inner and outer arcs of our shape.

```
struct RoundedAnnulusSector: BezierPathRenderable {
    // ...

    private var corner1: RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner { return RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner() }
    private var corner2: RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner { return RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner() }
    private var corner3: RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner { return RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner() }
    private var corner4: RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner { return RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner() }
    private var outerArc: Arc { ??? }
    private var innerArc: Arc { ??? }
}
```

#### Implementing `Arc`

Again, `Arc` is just another shape, that'll fulfill the same two roles as the others. From our familiarity with `UIBezierPath`'s arc APIs, we'll know that the arcs would need a center, radius, start/end angle, and an indicator of whether to draw them clockwise or counter-clockwise. So we can fill that out:

```
struct Arc: BezierPathRenderable {
    let center: CGPoint
    let radius: CGFloat
    let startAngle: CGFloat
    let endAngle: CGFloat
    let clockwise: Bool

    func render(into builder: BezierPathBuilder, _ path: UIBezierPath) {
        path.addArc(withCenter: center, radius:  radius,
                startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: clockwise)
    }
}
```

#### First approximation of `innerArc`/`outerArc`

Now we need to determine the arguments to initialize our arcs with. We'll start without rounded corners, so we'll just use our `startAngle`/`endAngle` directly, with our `innerRadius`/`outerRadius`.

```
struct RoundedAnnulusSector: BezierPathRenderable {
    // ...

    private var outerArc: Arc {
        return Arc(
            center: self.center,
            radius: self.outerRadius,
            startAngle: self.startAngle,
            endAngle: self.endAngle,
            clockwise: true
        )
    }

    private var innerArc: Arc {
        return Arc(
            center: self.center,
            radius: self.innerRadius,
            startAngle: self.endAngle,
            endAngle: self.startAngle,
            clockwise: false
        )
    }
}
```

#### Initial rendering

With these two parts complete, we can start drawing to see how it looks so far, by doing an initial implementation of `RoundedAnnulusSector.render(into:_:)`

```
struct RoundedAnnulusSector: BezierPathRenderable {
    // ...

    func render(into builder: BezierPathBuilder, _ path: BezierPath) {
        let components: [BezierPathRenderable] = [
            self.outerArc,
            self.innerArc,
        ]
        builder.append(contentsOf: components)
    }

}

extension BezierPathBuilder {
    func append<S: Sequence>(contentsOf renderables: S) where S.Element == BezierPathRenderable {
        for renderable in renderables {
            self.append(renderable)
        }
    }
}
```

As we progress, we can add more `BezierPathRenderable` components to this list. I saw this coming, so I made that `BezierPathBuilder` for handling sequences, so we can just feed it an array and have it automatically append all the elements within.

#### Stubbing `startAngleEdge`, `endAngleEdge`

This shape needs two straight lines. The first will connect corner 4 with corner 1 (which will be a radial line outwards from the center along the `startAngle`), and the second will connect corner 2 with corner 3 (which will be a radial line outwards from the center  along the `endAngle`. Let's put those in:

```
struct RoundedAnnulusSector: BezierPathRenderable {
    // ...

    func render(into builder: BezierPathBuilder, _ path: BezierPath) {
        let components: [BezierPathRenderable] = [
            self.outerArc,
            self.endAngleEdge,
            self.innerArc,
            self.startAngleEdge,
        ]
        builder.append(contentsOf: components)
    }

    // ...


    private var endAngleEdge: Line {
        return Line()
    }

    private var startAngleEdge: Line {
        return Line()
    }
}
```

#### Implementing `Line`

We can just stub out `Line`, but we know a line just connects two points. It's so simple we may as well just finish it:

```
struct Line: BezierPathRenderable {
    let start: CGPoint
    let end: CGPoint

    func render(into builder: BezierPathBuilder, _ path: BezierPath) {
        path.move(to: self.start)
        path.addLine(to: self.end)
    }
}
```

#### Implementation of `startAngleEdge`/`endAngleEdge`

Now we need to figure out what the start/end points will be for our two lines. It would be really convenient if our `RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner` had `startPoint: CGPoint` and `endPoint: CGPoint` properties.

```
struct RoundedAnnulusSector: BezierPathRenderable {
    // ...

    private var endAngleEdge: Line {
        return Line(
            start: self.corner2.endPoint,
              end: self.corner3.startPoint)
    }

    private var startAngleEdge: Line {
        return Line(
            start: self.corner4.endPoint,
              end: self.corner1.startPoint)
    }
}
```

#### First approximation of `startAngleEdge`/`endAngleEdge`

Let's fulfill our wish

```
struct RoundedAnnulusSector: BezierPathRenderable {
    // ...
    var startPoint: CGPoint { return .zero }
    var   endPoint: CGPoint { return .zero }
}
```

Because these are all implemented as `CGPoint.zero`, none of our edges would draw.

#### Second approximation of `startAngleEdge`/`endAngleEdge`

So let's implement some better approximation of `startPoint`/`endPoint`. Suppose our point had a `rawCornerPoint: CGPoint`. This would be a point that would be the location of the corner, if there was no rounding (i.e. rounding radius = 0). In the no-rounding world, our `startPoint`/`endPoint` would both be `rawCornerPoint`. Let's stub it and use it:

```
struct RoundedAnnulusSector: BezierPathRenderable {
    // ...

    var rawCornerPoint: CGPoint { return .zero }
    var startPoint: CGPoint { return self.rawCornerPoint }
    var   endPoint: CGPoint { return self.rawCornerPoint }
}
```

#### Implementing `rawCornerPoint`

Now, we'll need to derive it's real value. `rawCornerPoint` depends on two things:

1. the center of the parent shape,
2. the position of the corner, relative to the center of the parent shape. This itself relies on:

   1. the distance to the parent shape's center
   2. the angle relative to the parent shape's center

Each of these things is a parameter of our parent shape, so these properties will actually be stored (and initialized by the parent shape). We can then use them to compute the offset, and add that offset to the `parentCenter`.

```
struct RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner {
    let parentCenter: CGPoint
    let distanceToParentCenter: CGFloat
    let angleToParentCenter: CGFloat

    var rawCornerPoint: CGPoint {
        let inset = CGPoint(
            radius: self.distanceToParentCenter,
            angle: self.angleToParentCenter
        )

        return self.parentCenter + inset
    }

    // ...
}
```

Clearly, an initializer for `CGPoint` that initializes it from polar coordinates would be just wonderful.

Also, writing `.applying(CGAffineTransform(translationX: deltaX, y: deltaY)` is annoying, it would be nice to just have a `+` operator.

#### Implementing some `CGPoint` utilities

Let's fulfill more of our wishes:

```
// Follows UIBezierPath convention on angles.
// 0 is "right" at 3 o'clock, and angle increase clockwise.
extension CGPoint {
    init(radius: CGFloat, angle: CGFloat) {
        self.init(x: radius * cos(angle), y: radius * sin(angle))
    }


    static func + (l: CGPoint, r: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: l.x + r.x, y: l.y + r.y)
    }

    static func - (l: CGPoint, r: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: l.x - r.x, y: l.y - r.y)
    }
}
```

#### Populating the corners' fields

Now that our corners actually have stored properties, we can go back to our `RoundedAnnulusSector` and fill them in.

```
struct RoundedAnnulusSector: BezierPathRenderable {
    // ...
    private var corner1: RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner {
        return RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner(
            parentCenter: self.center,
            distanceToParentCenter: self.outerRadius,
            angleToParentCenter: self.startAngle
        )
    }

    private var corner2: RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner {
        return RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner(
            parentCenter: self.center,
            distanceToParentCenter: self.outerRadius,
            angleToParentCenter: self.endAngle
        )
    }

    private var corner3: RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner {
        return RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner(
            parentCenter: self.center,
            distanceToParentCenter: self.innerRadius,
            angleToParentCenter: self.endAngle
        )
    }

    private var corner4: RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner {
        return RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner(
            parentCenter: self.center,
            distanceToParentCenter: self.innerRadius,
            angleToParentCenter: self.startAngle

        )
    }
// ...
}
```

#### Second rendering

Our main shape's render list already contains our lines, but now that we've implemented an approximation of them, we can actually test them. If I've explained things correctly so far, at this point there should be a closed-looking shape, with sharp corners. Success! (I hope)

#### Rounding things off

Makes it sound like we're almost done, but no way haha, this is where the good stuff starts.

Firstly, we should add all the stuff that comes with roundedness. We know our rounded corners are going to be arcs, and luckily, we've already implemented those!

Arcs need a start and end angle, so we'll need those too. We can stub them with `0` and `2π`, so that we don't have to worry about the orientation of our rounded corners' arcs. For now, they'll just be full circles.

```
struct RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner {
    // ...
    let radius: CGFloat

    var arc: Arc {
        return Arc(center: rawCornerPoint, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
    }

    /// The angle at which this corner's arc starts.
    var startAngle: CGFloat { return 0 }

    /// The angle at which this corner's arc ends.
    var endAngle: CGFloat { return 2 * .pi }
}
```

#### Third rendering

Now that our corners have arcs, we can add those arcs to our render list for drawing:

```
struct RoundedAnnulusSector: BezierPathRenderable {
    let center: CGPoint
    let innerRadius: CGFloat
    let outerRadius: CGFloat
    let startAngle: CGFloat
    let endAngle: CGFloat
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat

    func render(into builder: BezierPathBuilder, _ path: UIBezierPath) {
        let components: [BezierPathRenderable] = [
            self.corner1.arc,
            self.outerArc,
            self.corner2.arc,
            self.endAngleEdge,
            self.corner3.arc,
            self.innerArc,
            self.corner4.arc,
            self.startAngleEdge,
        ]
        builder.append(contentsOf: components)
    }
}
```

And behold, circles!

But uh'oh, they're centred around the `rawCornerPoint`. I suppose that shouldn't be surprising, because that's literally how we defined our `Arc`.

#### Insetting the center

But to get this right, we need to inset the center of the arc. Let's call it the `center`. The center needs to be inset, so that it's closer towards the "inside" of `RoundedAnnulusSector`, so that after adding the corner radius, the stroke lines up with the rest of the shape.

This insetting consists of two components:
1. The center needs to be rotated, relative to the `parentCenter` by an angle (call it `rotationalInsetAngle`), which makes it lay on the inner or outer arc, so that its arc extends rotationally to reach the radius

Here's a photo for reference:

[image: Corner detail diagram]

1. The blue circle is our corner's current circle, centred on `rawCornerPoint`.
2. The small arrow marked `1` is the rotational component of the inset.
3. The pink circle is our corner's circle, after the rotational inset.
4. The small arrow marked `2` is the radial translation component of the inset
5. The green circle is our desired corner circle, centred on `center`.
6. The dashed arrow marked `offset` is the offset between `rawCornerPoint` and `center`, obtained as a composition of the rotional and radial translation components.

```
struct RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner {
    // ...
    /// The center of this rounded corner's arc
    ///
    /// ...after insetting from the `rawCornerPoint`, so that this rounded corner's arc
    /// aligns perfectly with the curves adjacent to it.
    var center: CGPoint {
        return self.rawCornerPoint
            .rotated(around: self.parentCenter, by: self.rotationalInsetAngle)
            .translated(towards: self.edgeAngle, by: self.radialInsetDistance)
    }
}
```

We have a long wish list here: `rotationalInsetAngle`, `radialInsetDistance`, `CGPoint.rotated(around:by:)`, `CGPoint.translated(towards:, by:)`.

#### More CGPoint utilities

Luckily, these are pretty easy to implement, now that we have the polar initializer.

```
extension CGPoint {
    func translated(towards angle: CGFloat, by r: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        return self + CGPoint(radius: r, angle: angle)
    }

    func rotated(around pivot: CGPoint, by angle: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        return (self - pivot).applying(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)) + pivot
    }
}
```

#### Getting stuck with `rotationalInsetAngle`, `radialInsetDistance`

This is where the shit hits the fan. We know that we have to inset our corner by translating it over by `radius`. But in which direction?

The inner two corners (#3 and #4) need to translate radially *away* from the parent, whereas the outer two corners (#1 and #3) need to translate radially *inwards* towards the parent.

Similarly, our rotional inset also need to vary. For the two corners on the starting edge (#1 and #4), we need to inset *clockwise* from the `startEdge`, whereas the two corners on the ending edge (#2 and #3) need to inset by *counter-clockwise* from the `endEdge`.

But our data model so far only tells our corners where they are in terms of an angle and a distance. It doesn't specify which side they need to stay on relative the defined `distanceFromCenter` and `angleToParentCenter`.

This will need some pretty big refactoring.

#### Implementing `RadialPosition` and `RotationalPosition`

Lets implement a type called `RadialPosition`. It'll capture not just a radial position (i.e. a distance form a central point), but also which side of that distance to "stay on". A struct containing a `radialDistance: CGFloat` and `isInsideOfRadialDistance: Bool` would do, but I know I've frequently made lots of bugs stemming from improperly handling conditions. Instead, I'll use a two case enum, where the inside/outside distinction is more explicit, and harder to miss. Because enum associated values are cumbersome to access, I'll add a helper computed property, `distanceFromCenter`, to hide away that annoying `switch` statement.

```
struct RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner {
   // ...
    enum RadialPosition {
        case outside(ofRadius: CGFloat)
        case  inside(ofRadius: CGFloat)

        var distanceFromCenter: CGFloat {
            switch self {
            case .outside(ofRadius: let d), .inside(ofRadius: let d): return d
            }
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Next, I'll do a similar thing for `RotationalPosition`:

```
struct RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner {
   // ...
    enum RotationalPosition {
        case cw(of: CGFloat)
        case ccw(of: CGFloat)

        var edgeAngle: CGFloat {
            switch self {
            case .cw(of: let angle), .ccw(of: let angle): return angle
            }
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Now I'll have to remove the existing `distanceToParentCenter: CGFloat` and `angleToParentCenter: CGFloat` properties and replace them with these new models. We need to migrate their call sites to `radialPosition.distanceFromCenter` and `RotationalPosition. edgeAngle`. This is the final set of stored properties for `RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner`:

```
struct RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner {
    let parentCenter: CGPoint
    let radius: CGFloat
    let radialPosition: RadialPosition
    let rotationalPosition: RotationalPosition

    // ...

    /// The location of the corner, if this rounded wasn't rounded.
    private var rawCornerPoint: CGPoint {
        let inset = CGPoint(
            radius: self.radialPosition.distanceFromCenter,
            angle: self.rotationalPosition.edgeAngle
        )

        return self.parentCenter + inset
    }

    // ...
}
```

And we'll have to update our corner definitions to provide this new data. These are the final set of definitions for the corners.

```
struct RoundedAnnulusSector: BezierPathRenderable {
    // ...
    private var corner1: RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner {
        return RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner(
            parentCenter: self.center,
            radius: self.cornerRadius,
            radialPosition: .inside(ofRadius: self.outerRadius),
            rotationalPosition: .cw(of: self.startAngle)
        )
    }

    private var corner2: RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner {
        return RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner(
            parentCenter: self.center,
            radius: self.cornerRadius,
            radialPosition: .inside(ofRadius: self.outerRadius),
            rotationalPosition: .ccw(of: self.endAngle)
        )
    }

    private var corner3: RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner {
        return RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner(
            parentCenter: self.center,
            radius: self.cornerRadius,
            radialPosition: .outside(ofRadius: self.innerRadius),
            rotationalPosition: .ccw(of: self.endAngle)
        )
    }

    private var corner4: RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner {
        return RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner(
            parentCenter: self.center,
            radius: self.cornerRadius,
            radialPosition: .outside(ofRadius: self.innerRadius),
            rotationalPosition: .cw(of: self.startAngle)
        )
    }
    // ...
}
```

#### Fourth rendering

Running this code again, we see that now the circles are still centred on their `rawCornerPoint`, but this is good. It means our refactoring hasn't broken our already-working features. If we had unit tests all along, this is where they'd be useful.

## To be continued

in [my next answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57919716/3141234), because I just got a StackOverflow error that I double many people have had before:

[image: Body is Limited to 30000 characters; you entered 31245]

Answer (score 1):

Continued from [the first part of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57919683/3141234)

---

#### Another try at `rotationalInsetAngle`, `radialInsetDistance`

Now that are corners are aware of what side they are relative to their distance and angle, we can implement our `rotationalInsetAngle`, `radialInsetDistance`.

`radialInsetDistance` is easy. We just move closer or further from the middle, by `self.radius`, depending on whether we're on the inside or outside.

```
struct RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner { 
    // ...

    /// The distance towards/away from the disk's center
    /// where this corner's center is going to be
    internal var radialInsetDistance: CGFloat {
        switch self.radialPosition {
        case  .inside(_): return -self.radius // negative: towards center
        case .outside(_): return +self.radius // positive: away from center
        }
    }
}
```

The `rotationalInsetAngle` is a bit trickier, you'll need to bust out a notepad and do your best to recall high school trig.

```
struct RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner { 
    // ...
    /// The angular inset (in radians) from the disk's edge
    /// where this corner's center is going to be
    internal var rotationalInsetAngle: CGFloat {
        let angle = ???
        switch self.rotationalPosition {
        case .ccw(_): return -angle // negative: ccw from the edge
        case  .cw(_): return +angle // postiive:  cw from the edge
        }
    }
}
```

We know we need to rotate by some angle, called it `angle`, whose magnitude is always the same, but whose sign depending on whether our corner is before the start or after before the end edge.

We know that after our translation, our corner circle's stroke will overlap the parent shape's edges/arcs. That distance is the `self.radius`, and it forms the "opposite" side a the right triangle. The hypotenuse is the radial we're rotating around, with a length of `self.radialPosition.distanceFromCenter`. Given that we have an `opposite` (`o`) and a hypotenuse (`h`), the correct trig function for the job is `sin`. `angle = sin(o / h)`. In context:

```
struct RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner { 
    // ...
    /// The angular inset (in radians) from the disk's edge
    /// where this corner's center is going to be
    internal var rotationalInsetAngle: CGFloat {
        let angle = sin(self.radius / self.radialPosition.distanceFromCenter)
        switch self.rotationalPosition {
        case .ccw(_): return -angle // negative: ccw from the edge
        case  .cw(_): return +angle // postiive:  cw from the edge
        }
    }
}
```

#### Ditching `rawCornerPoint`

Hippity hoppity, our `center` computed property should now world properly, because our newly implemented `rotationalInsetAngle` and `radialInsetDistance`.

We can update our corners' arcs to use it:

```
struct RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner { 
    // ...
    var arc: Arc {
        return Arc(center: center, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
    }
    // ...
}
```

#### Fifth rendering

If all has gone well, you should see the corner's circle are now at the right place (centred on `center`s, not `rawCornerPoint`s).

#### Decircularifying

Up until now, we've rendered the rounded corners as full circles. That was useful for getting it going, but now we can fix it. Let's properly implement the `startAngle`/`endAngle` computed properties to derive the appropriate start and end angles for each rounded corner.

These are easy. Every rounded corner starts going with the edge angle, perpendicular to it, against it, or perpendicular the other way. The arc then continues for a quarter turn, so we can just obtain the `endAngle` by adding a quarter turn (2π) to `startAngle`.

```
struct RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner { 
    // ...
    /// The angle at which this corner's arc starts.
    var startAngle: CGFloat {
        switch (radialPosition, rotationalPosition) {
        case let ( .inside(_),  .cw(of: edgeAngle)): return edgeAngle + (3 * .pi/2)
        case let ( .inside(_), .ccw(of: edgeAngle)): return edgeAngle + (0 * .pi/2)
        case let (.outside(_), .ccw(of: edgeAngle)): return edgeAngle + (1 * .pi/2)
        case let (.outside(_),  .cw(of: edgeAngle)): return edgeAngle + (2 * .pi/2)
        }
    }


    /// The angle at which this corner's arc ends.
    var endAngle: CGFloat {
        return self.startAngle + .pi/2 // A quarter turn clockwise from the start
    }
}
```

#### Sixth rendering

We're almost there! Now our circles are no more. We have rounded corners, centred on the correctly inset `center` points, arcing in the right arcs.

The only remaining issue, is that our `startAngleEdge`, `endAngleEdge`, `innerArc`, and `outerArc` don't terminate where the rounded corners terminate.

#### Fixing the edges

We can now replace our definition of `startPoint`/`endPoint`, which until now been computed as being `rawCornerPoint`.

Computing these is as easy translating our point, towards the start/end angle, by a distance of `radius`. Oh look, we already made a tool for that!

```
struct RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner {
    // ...
    /// The point at which this corner's arc starts.
    var startPoint: CGPoint {
        return self.center.translated(towards: startAngle, by: radius)
    }

    /// The point at which this corner's arc ends.
    var endPoint: CGPoint {
        return self.center.translated(towards: endAngle, by: radius)
    }
    // ...
}
```

#### Seventh rendering

Now our edges are in the right place!

#### Fixing the arcs

Fixing the arcs is easy. We know each corner's `rotationalInsetAngle`, we just need to add it to our start/end angles, so that they start/end later/earlier as necessary:

```
struct RoundedAnnulusSectorCorner {
    // ...
    private var outerArc: Arc {
        return Arc(
            center: self.center,
            radius: self.outerRadius,
            startAngle: self.startAngle + self.corner1.rotationalInsetAngle,
            endAngle: self.endAngle + self.corner2.rotationalInsetAngle,
            clockwise: true
        )
    }

    private var innerArc: Arc {
        return Arc(
            center: self.center,
            radius: self.innerRadius,
            startAngle: self.endAngle + self.corner3.rotationalInsetAngle,
            endAngle: self.startAngle + self.corner4.rotationalInsetAngle,
            clockwise: false
        )
    }
    // ...
}
```

#### Eighth rendering

It's done! Here's the final [final gist](https://gist.github.com/amomchilov/1ac8e63001bd703cd4e460ba57b4df2f), though I do strongly encourage following along and learning about the process.

Comment: Thank you for your very elaborate answer. I fully agree with your preface and my production code is nowhere near what I posted here. I usually am a big believer in DRY and fully agree that the code is, in lack of a better word, messy. I wrote this in a playground in order to give my paper drafts an outcome, but got stuck doing so.

Comment: I’ve read through most of it now and I like your train of thought. It is well written and I would actually recommend you write a blogpost about it.
In the end, my main difficulty was with trigonometry and trying to calculate it from the wrong point; I was so focused on calculating it from the latest endAngle and having that as my center point that I got stuck there. Thanks again!

Comment: @PaulPeelen Thanks for the encouragement, I will :) The trig might be difficult from the onset, but if you look closely, you'll see that besides my polar coordinate `CGPoint` initializer (which uses 1 sin and 1 cos, but it's a readily available established formula that you could just look up), I only use a single `sin`. Such is the power of well abstracted logic