# How do I round the corners of this Shape in SwifUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm making a pie graph, and need to round the corners of each piece, but I cannot figure it out. I guess there are some very complex math in order to do this.

Please help!
Thanks

```
struct SliceShape: Shape {
    var startAngle: Double
    var endAngle: Double

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        let center = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)

        path.addArc(center: center,
                    radius: min(rect.width/2, rect.height/2),
                    startAngle: .degrees(startAngle),
                    endAngle: .degrees(endAngle),
                    clockwise: false)
        path.addLine(to: center)

        path.closeSubpath()

        return path
    }
}

struct PieSliceView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SliceShape(startAngle: 10, endAngle: 90)
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I adapted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57912571/5133585) by Alexander, which generates a `UIBezierPath` for a similar shape with rounded corners, and wrote it using SwiftUI's APIs.

```
extension CGPoint {
    init(radius: CGFloat, angle: Angle) {
        self.init(x: radius * cos(angle.radians), y: radius * sin(angle.radians))
    }
    
    func translated(towards angle: Angle, by r: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        return self + CGPoint(radius: r, angle: angle)
    }
    
    func rotated(around pivot: CGPoint, by angle: Angle) -> CGPoint {
        return (self - pivot).applying(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle.radians)) + pivot
    }
    
    static func + (l: CGPoint, r: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: l.x + r.x, y: l.y + r.y)
    }
    
    static func - (l: CGPoint, r: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: l.x - r.x, y: l.y - r.y)
    }
}

protocol BezierPathRenderable {
    func render(_ path: inout Path)
}

struct RoundedDiskSectorCorner {
    
    enum RotationalPosition {
        case cw(of: Angle)
        case ccw(of: Angle)
        
        var edgeAngle: Angle {
            switch self {
            case .cw(of: let angle), .ccw(of: let angle): return angle
            }
        }
    }
    
    let parentCenter: CGPoint
    let radius: CGFloat
    let radialPosition: CGFloat
    let rotationalPosition: RotationalPosition

    var arc: Arc {
        return Arc(center: center, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
    }
    
    /// The location of the corner, if this rounded wasn't rounded.
    private var rawCornerPoint: CGPoint {
        let inset = CGPoint(
            radius: self.radialPosition,
            angle: self.rotationalPosition.edgeAngle
        )
        
        return self.parentCenter + inset
    }
    
    
    /// The center of this rounded corner's arc
    ///
    /// ...after insetting from the `rawCornerPoint`, so that this rounded corner's arc
    /// aligns perfectly with the curves adjacent to it.
    var center: CGPoint {
        return self.rawCornerPoint
            .rotated(around: self.parentCenter, by: self.rotationalInsetAngle)
            .translated(towards: self.rotationalPosition.edgeAngle, by: self.radialInsetDistance)
    }
    
    /// The distance towards/away from the disk's center
    /// where this corner's center is going to be
    internal var radialInsetDistance: CGFloat {
        -self.radius
    }
    
    /// The angular inset (in radians) from the disk's edge
    /// where this corner's center is going to be
    internal var rotationalInsetAngle: Angle {
        let angle = Angle.radians(sin(self.radius / self.radialPosition))
        switch self.rotationalPosition {
        case .ccw(_): return -angle // negative: ccw from the edge
        case  .cw(_): return angle // positive:  cw from the edge
        }
    }

    /// The angle at which this corner's arc starts.
    var startAngle: Angle {
        switch rotationalPosition {
        case let .cw(of: edgeAngle): return edgeAngle + .radians(3 * .pi/2)
        case let .ccw(of: edgeAngle): return edgeAngle + .radians(0 * .pi/2)
        }
    }
    
    
    /// The angle at which this corner's arc ends.
    var endAngle: Angle {
        return self.startAngle + .radians(.pi / 2) // A quarter turn clockwise from the start
    }
    
    
    /// The point at which this corner's arc starts.
    var startPoint: CGPoint {
        return self.center.translated(towards: startAngle, by: radius)
    }

    /// The point at which this corner's arc ends.
    var endPoint: CGPoint {
        return self.center.translated(towards: endAngle, by: radius)
    }
}

struct Arc: BezierPathRenderable {
    let center: CGPoint
    let radius: CGFloat
    let startAngle: Angle
    let endAngle: Angle
    let clockwise: Bool
    
    func render(_ path: inout Path) {
        path.addArc(center: center, radius:  radius,
                startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: !clockwise)
    }
}

struct Line: BezierPathRenderable {
    
    let start: CGPoint
    let end: CGPoint
    
    func render(_ path: inout Path) {
//        path.move(to: self.start)
        path.addLine(to: self.end)
    }
}

struct RoundedDiskSector {
    let center: CGPoint
    let outerRadius: CGFloat
    let startAngle: Angle
    let endAngle: Angle
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat
    let tipRadius: CGFloat
    
    var components: [BezierPathRenderable] { [
        self.corner1.arc,
        self.outerArc,
        self.corner2.arc,
        self.corner3,
    ] }
    
    private var corner1: RoundedDiskSectorCorner {
        return RoundedDiskSectorCorner(
            parentCenter: self.center,
            radius: self.cornerRadius,
            radialPosition: self.outerRadius,
            rotationalPosition: .cw(of: self.startAngle)
        )
    }
    
    private var corner2: RoundedDiskSectorCorner {
        return RoundedDiskSectorCorner(
            parentCenter: self.center,
            radius: self.cornerRadius,
            radialPosition: self.outerRadius,
            rotationalPosition: .ccw(of: self.endAngle)
        )
    }
    
    private var corner3: ArcFromTangent {
        return ArcFromTangent(
            tangent1End: center,
            tangent2End: corner1.startPoint,
            radius: tipRadius
        )
    }
    
    private var outerArc: Arc {
        return Arc(
            center: self.center,
            radius: self.outerRadius,
            startAngle: self.startAngle + self.corner1.rotationalInsetAngle,
            endAngle: self.endAngle + self.corner2.rotationalInsetAngle,
            clockwise: true
        )
    }
}

struct ArcFromTangent: BezierPathRenderable {
    let tangent1End: CGPoint
    let tangent2End: CGPoint
    let radius: CGFloat
    func render(_ path: inout Path) {
        path.addArc(tangent1End: tangent1End, tangent2End: tangent2End, radius: radius)
    }
}
```

This essentially gives an array of `BezierPathRenderable`s, which we can use to make a `Path`:

```
struct RoundedSector: Shape {
    let startAngle: Angle
    let endAngle: Angle
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat
    let tipRadius: CGFloat
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let strokeWidth: CGFloat = CGFloat(min(rect.width, rect.height) * 0.25)
        let innerRadius = (min(rect.width, rect.height) - strokeWidth*2) / 2.0
        let outerRadius = (min(rect.width, rect.height)) / 2.0
        
        let shape = RoundedDiskSector(
            center: .init(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY),
            outerRadius: outerRadius - cornerRadius * 2,
            startAngle: startAngle,
            endAngle: endAngle,
            cornerRadius: cornerRadius,
            tipRadius: tipRadius
        )
        return Path { p in
            for component in shape.components {
                component.render(&p)
            }
            p.closeSubpath()
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ZStack {
    RoundedSector(startAngle: .degrees(0), endAngle: .degrees(45), cornerRadius: 10, tipRadius: 7)
        .stroke(.black)
    RoundedSector(startAngle: .degrees(45), endAngle: .degrees(60), cornerRadius: 10, tipRadius: 1.5)
        .stroke(.black)
    RoundedSector(startAngle: .degrees(60), endAngle: .degrees(100), cornerRadius: 10, tipRadius: 5)
        .stroke(.black)
    RoundedSector(startAngle: .degrees(100), endAngle: .degrees(360), cornerRadius: 10, tipRadius: 10)
        .stroke(.black)
}
```

Output:

[image]

Note that the `tipRadius` should change depending on the size of the sector. The smaller the sector, the smaller the tip radius should be. Otherwise the very small slices will be really short - it'll look like this:

[image]

---

Of course, there is also the option of just using SwiftCharts' `SectorMark`, where you can simply use [`cornerRadius`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts/chartcontent/cornerradius(_:style:)):

```
let foos = [Foo(x: 1), Foo(x: 2), Foo(x: 3), Foo(x: 4)]
var body: some View {
    Chart(foos) { foo in
        SectorMark(angle: .value("X", foo.x), angularInset: 10).cornerRadius(10)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your answer is sufficient, creating a pie chart is quite complex. Given the mathematics of a circle and combining that with specific sizes, but you definitely on the right track!

You can quite easily create multiple circle arcs using your code by looping it for different sizes and calculating the angles out of 2pi. A quick altercation is changing the arc to start at -90, so the chart starts at the top of the page:

```
struct SliceShape: View {
    var pieSliceData: SliceData

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                Path { path in
                    let width: CGFloat = min(geometry.size.width, geometry.size.height)
                    let height = width
                
                    let center = CGPoint(x: width * 0.5, y: height * 0.5)
                
                    path.move(to: center)
                
                    path.addArc(
                        center: center,
                        radius: width * 0.5,
                        startAngle: Angle(degrees: -90.0) + pieSliceData.startAngle,
                        endAngle: Angle(degrees: -90.0) + pieSliceData.endAngle,
                    clockwise: false)
                }
                .fill(pieSliceData.color)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where `SliceData` is:

```
struct SliceData {
    var startAngle: Angle
    var endAngle: Angle
    var color: Color
}
```

Then, we need to create a `PieChartView` to calculate the angles for each slice but also combine them through the use of a `ZStack`:

```
struct PieChartView: View {
    public let values: [Double]
    public var colors: [Color]

    var slices: [SliceData] {
        let sum = values.reduce(0, +)
        var endDeg: Double = 0
        var slices: [SliceData] = []
    
        for (i, value) in values.enumerated() {
            let degrees: Double = value * 360 / sum
            slices.append(SliceData(startAngle: Angle(degrees: endDeg), endAngle: Angle(degrees: endDeg + degrees), color: self.colors[i]))
            endDeg += degrees
        }
        return slices
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            ForEach(0..<self.values.count) { i in
                SliceShape(pieSliceData: self.slices[i])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then finally combining to give:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PieChartView(values: [800, 400, 200], colors: [Color.blue, Color.green, Color.orange])
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

This will produce the following graph:

[image: Pie Chart Picture]

Comment: Thanks for response, however, It's the rounded corners bit I'm looking to solve, not to build the whole pie.